# Logical Operators and Precedence

Tags: php, logic, php-5.3, logical-operators

So I just did some random test and understand the fundamentals of Precedence and the **||** and **or** operators but I'm having trouble understanding why $f changes:

```
$f = 0 || 1;

if ($f === 1){
    echo "TRUE - $f";
}else{ 
   echo "FALSE - $f";
}
$f = 0 or 1;

if ($f === 0){
    echo "TRUE - $f";
}else{ 
   echo "FALSE - $f";
}
```

Thanks for some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal to evaluate always to `True`. The reason is that OR means if that one of the values is True it will take this one.

**Update to your new question:**

The answer is that "||" has a greater precedence than "or"

```
// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

You can learn more at the PHP manual website [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) which I found this example

Comment: Why is it that if ($f === 0 or 1) still evaluates to true even though $f is empty?

Comment: As I can see you are new here so if this answer solve your problem please mark it as the correct answer in order to help other guys having the same problem

Comment: Because OR statements will evaluate to true if one of their parameters is True. AND statements will evaluate to True only if all of their parameters are True

Comment: Updated question, the actual question I was asking, sorry for typos, will accept once you update answer :)!

Comment: The question is in regard to why $f changes btw.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, think you should mention that the precedence goes in this order: ||, =, or, thats where the confusion was :p! thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is the same as :

```
if (($f = 0) or 1){ 
    // $f is being assigned the value 0, and the condition evaluates 0 or 1,
    // 1 being equivalent to true, the condition is always true.
    echo "TRUE - $f";
}else{
    echo "FALSE - $f";
}
```

and

```
if ($f = (0 || 1)){ // which gives $f = true which returns true
    echo "TRUE - $f";
}else{
    echo "FALSE - $f";
}
```

if you want to check if $f is equal to a value or another you would do

```
if ($f === 0 or $f === 1)
```

Be aware that in php, by default an int 1 will be evaluated to bool true unless you do a strict comparison === or !==

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here: "if ($f = 0 or 1){" :

"=" means you give the variable $f the value 0

You should use :

- "==" : checks if the values are equal
- "===" : checks if the left variable is identical to the right variable (value, type, etc.)